# Computing a single probability out of a joint probability

Tags: probability

Given the joint probability and the factored term:

$$ P(S,T,G,F,B) = P(G|B,F) \cdot P(S|T,F) \cdot P(T|B) \cdot P(B) \cdot P(F)  $$

I want to compute $P(S = s)$, thus I want to compute

$$\sum_{T,G,F,B} P(S = s, T,G,F,B)$$

Since I want to do the concrete calculation by hand, I would like to eliminate some terms in order to ease the process. Is there anything which could be done? I am thinking of making use of $$\sum_X P(X|Y) = 1$$

Comment: Are $S,T,G,F,B$ random variables?  Then there is no such thing as 
$P(S,T,G,F,B)$, but perhaps you mean $P(S=s,T=t,G=g,F=f,B=b)$ (assuming these are all discrete).

Comment: @RobertIsrael Exactly, sorry for my sloppy notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you are really saying
$$ P(S=s,T=t,G=g,F=f,B=b) = P(G=g|B=b,F=f)P(S=s|T=t,F=f)P(T=t|B=b)P(B=b)P(F=f)$$
for discrete random variables $S,T,G,F,B$.
Sum both sides over $g$ and this says
$$ P(S=s,T=t,F=f,B=b) = P(S=s|T=t,F=f)P(T=t|B=b)P(B=b)P(F=f)$$
Now $P(T=t) = \sum_b P(T=t|B=b) P(B=b)$, so calculate this for each $t$.  Then summing over $b$,
$$P(S=s,T=t,F=f) = P(S=s|T=t,F=f) P(T=t) P(F=f)$$
To calculate $P(S=s)$, you'll have to do a double sum of this over all $t$ and $f$.